# Experimental dispatching with std::apply

Tags: c++

I would like to have a general function 'request' which could accept a tuple of any number of arguments. I want the 'request' function to dispatch the call to a number of other functions, depending on the number of arguments (of course the interface of the functions must match).

I wrote this code, but it only works if I call function of one type inside the 'request'. As soon as I uncomment the dispatching mechanism (else -> dispatch to fun5) everything stops compiling.

The problem is that the body of function 'request', created for the case of dispatching to function with two parameters, must compile, and then there is a function with 5 arguments inside it, to which the tuple of 2 arguments cannot be applied. And vice versa. Classic problem with templates. I know that I could somehow apply SFINAE concept to this problem, but I somehow don't know how (I am not as strong in MPL programming).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/tuple>

enum class type { v2, v5 };

void fun2(int i1, int i2)
{
    std::cout << "fun2 called, i1 = " << i1 << ", i2 = " << i2 << std::endl;
}

void fun5(bool b1, float f1, int i, char c, bool b2)
{
    std::cout << "fun5 called with: " << std::boolalpha << b1 << ", " << f1 << ", " << i << ", " << c << ", " << b2 << std::endl;
}

template <typename F, typename... T>
void dispatch(F f, T... args)
{
    std::experimental::apply(f, args...);    
}

template <typename... T>
void request(type t, T... args)
{
    if (t == type::v2)
      dispatch(fun2, args...);
    // else
    //  dispatch(fun5, args...);
}

int main()
{
   auto v2 = std::make_tuple(1,1);
   request(type::v2, v2);

  // auto v5 = std::make_tuple(true, 1.5f, 3, 'c', false);
  // request(type::v5, v5);   
}
```

How can I make this work? What kind of dispatching mechanism I need here to make this work?

Comment: If you have `std::apply`, you also have `if constexpr` :)

Comment: I tried it, no effect. I mean I tried replacing 'if' inside 'request' with 'if constexpr'. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I should do that. Thanks for the info. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to tag dispatch (which I highly recommend [as per @Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307797/27678)) would be to create your own function object that accepts a `type` as a non-type template argument so that we can take advantage of [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
template<type t>
struct request
{
    template<class... T>
    void operator()(T... args) const
    {
        if constexpr(t == type::v2)
            dispatch(fun2, args...);
        else
            dispatch(fun5, args...);
    }
};
```

The downside is that you have to construct one to make your call:

```
auto v2 = std::make_tuple(1, 1);
request<type::v2>()(v2);

auto v5 = std::make_tuple(true, 1.5f, 3, 'c', false);
request<type::v5>()(v5);
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8OJebD4kHUdmFOLY)

---

A variation on this approach is to instead have a `static` `apply` function in your `request` class like so:

```
template<type t>
struct request{
  template<class... T>
  static void apply(T... args){/*..*/}
}
```

And then a call to it would look like this instead (no funky empty braces):

```
request<type::v2>::apply(v2);
```

#### [Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y1XuwQZ8LD3TCsSB)

Comment: Hm... so it may work, but not for my case, when I want a standalone function?

Comment: I managed to make it work with free function as well. I had to also provide a type as template parameter, and the call is also ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an enumeration to select what to do, I suggest you use *tags* and tag structures instead. Then you can simply select the right `dispatch` function using simple function overloading.

Perhaps something like

```
namespace type
{
    struct v2_tag {};
    struct v5_tag {};

    v2_tag v2;
    v5_tag v5;
}

template<typename... T>
void request(type::v2_tag, T... args)
{
    dispatch(fun2, args...);
}

template<typename... T>
void request(type::v5_tag, T... args)
{
    dispatch(fun5, args...);
}
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Yes, I received the same result already with the tag-dispatching mechanism, but I don't like this solution either. It forces me to write a copy of 'request' function for every number of arguments. I will have 5 copies of request function in my code. Or 10, or 50 in the future. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is there any way to keep only one 'request' function and make it clever enough to know how to dispatch tuple with 2 arguments and in other case a tuple with 5 arguments?

Comment: @YotKay Having a big `if ... else if ... else` chain, or a big `switch` statement, makes the code harder to read, less easy to understand, less maintainable, and using enumerations this way is generally frowned upon. It's really no better than selecting code-paths using `typeid`. *Also* it's not really possible to create such code, since the `T` will be different depending on how it's called, and that makes it impossible to correctly compile all code paths.